# CSR scipy matrix does not update after updating its values

Tags: python

I have the following code in python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
M = csr_matrix(np.ones([2, 2],dtype=np.int32))
print(M)
print(M.data.shape)
for i in range(np.shape(M)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(M)[1]):
        if i==j:
            M[i,j] = 0
print(M)
print(M.data.shape)
```

The output of the first 2 prints is:

```
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    1
(4,)
```

The code is changing the value of the same index (i==j) and setting the value to zero.
After executing the loops then the output of the last 2 prints is:

```
  (0, 0)    0
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    0
(4,)
```

If I understand the concept of sparse matrices correctly, it should not be the case. It should not show me the zero values and the output of last 2 prints should be like this:

```
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
(2,)
```

Does anyone have explanation for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that CSR does not remove the zeros by default. You will first have to call `eliminate_zeros()` on your object. Once you do this you will see that the data contains only the non zero elements of your matrix.

after running the loop in your code:

```
print(M)
```

gives

```
  (0, 0)    0
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    0
```

let us inspect the data

```
print(M.data)
```

we see that the zero elements are stored,

```
[0 1 1 0]
```

let us remove the zero elements to make our matrix sparse

```
M.eliminate_zeros()
```

and inspect whether the matrix is sparse,

```
print(M.data)
```

this confirms that the zero elements are removed and hence the matrix is sparse,

```
[1 1]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Sparse matrix** is a matrix that has most of its elements as zero. Matrix on the other side of it, is **Dense**. [csr_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) creates an all zero element matrix and if you are updating the elements as

```
m[i,j] = 0.
```

Well, you're not really doing anything as elements are already zero. For example

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
mat = csr_matrix((2,2), dtype = np.int16).toarray()
print mat,"\n"
for i in range(np.shape(mat)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(mat)[1]):
        mat[i,j] = i+j
print mat
```

gives

```
[[0 0]
 [0 0]]

[[0 1]
 [1 2]]
```

which is true, the first matrix,an all zero matrix created and the second, is the updated one.

**Edit:**

After substituting when $i==j$, the resultant matrix still has four elements but this time with $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ indices being $0$. So the result is

```
(0, 0)    0
(0, 1)    1
(1, 0)    1
(1, 1)    0
(4,)
```

But explaining your expected result

```
(0, 1)    1
(1, 0)    1
(2,)
```

The result has basically two elements with $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ indices being $1$ and $1$ and shape is just $(2,)$ when flattened which does not make sense as matrix is still of size $(4,)$ . So python output is basically giving all the values in the matrix with index. If I am rightly understanding what you are assuming, since the matrix is sparse, you are expecting it to give only the values where the elements are non-zero, well this does not do that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it does not help much since before changing the values, you are converting the csr matrix to normal numpy matrix. I have edited the question and elaborated bit more about my problem.